# Ugly shadow in gnome top bar caused by a theme. How do I hide that?

Tags: shell, gnome, theme, toolbar

Hello, I'm using the 'Canta' theme with my gnome DE. I very like the theme, but it has one problem. This ugly shadow is applied on buttons in the top bar, when focused:

[image]

(The blue thing in the picture)

Could I modify the CSS file of the theme, so that it won't display this any more? And if so, what is the CSS class name of this element?

Comment: figure out the hex color code ... look for it in CSS files ... also look for color names containing "blue"

Comment: The problem is that this color is used in many other things of the shell - like on some button effects etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### **EDIT:** The shadow is caused by line 1210 of `gnome-shell.css`

Just delete it, log out and back in and it works

Comment: this answer is not very useful ... if gnome-shell.css changes, then line 1210 may no longer be applicable ... please add a copy of the applicable section in the css file so that the line can still be found